# Making Dreamweaver learn new syntax

Tags: dreamweaver

Alright, so since PHP 5.3, users can define anonymous functions. One way which I use anonymous functions is by storing them in an array:

```
array (
  'protocol' => function() {
        echo 'something';
    }
);
```

However, Dreamweaver CS5 doesn't like this and throws me a syntax error and it is quite annoying when trying to find other real syntax errors that might occur on my code. Is there a way to add new syntax into Dreamweaver's configuration and ignore this?

Comment: That _does_ have invalid syntax; it needs an ending `;` in the echo line

Comment: @ChrisForrence no, this is simply an example. And yes, technically there should be a semicolon there. This is not the problem I'm facing. My code is not broken. I'm simply faced with the fact the Dreamweaver doesn't like functions inside arrays.

Comment: Fair enough (although it should be `echo 'something';`). It does looks like you'd need CS5.5 though, as zeroCoder says in their answer.

Comment: @ChrisForrence yea, I'm looking into it now. They should have made an easier way to do this rather than having to upgrade software versions: perhaps like importing new definitions via a file or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According To This Link at [Adobe Forums Website](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/653117?tstart=0)
    Dreamweaver supports any version of PHP. However, Dreamweaver's code hints support only PHP 5.2.

Dynamic Code Hinting in DW CS5 supports PHP 5.2, but DW CS5.5 supports PHP 5.3.

Comment: Looking into it now. Thank you!